# Encrypting passwords in collectd config

Tags: encryption, password-hash, collectd

I have looked everywhere and couldn't find any way of encrypting passwords in the collectd.conf file.

Right now I have a collectd config file with the Postgres plugin install and loaded, it requires the connection credentials for each database I'm querying.

This means right now i have the password saved in cleartext in the configuration file.

is there any way to encrypt/hash the passwords in the config file, or even encrypt the entire file(but still make collectd work with it)

EDIT: im working on a linux server (rhel 7.4, using collectd 5.8.0)

Comment: Have you seen this: https://nimblegecko.com/how-to-store-login-details-securely-in-application-config-file/

Comment: i forgot to mention im working on a linux server, so using .NET isnt an option for me.
Thanks though

Comment: Have you tried to lock the file permissions down so that only `collectd` user has permissions to read it? Encryption only moves the problem, as you still have to manage the key and keep it secret. You absolutely cannot hash it as you need to pass it to something else down the line.